# OpenCV trackbar performance in OSX

Tags: performance, macos, opencv

I've just noticed that performance of openCV is drastically slowed down when a trackbar is present in a window with changing image from camera or a movie frame. What could be done resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The solution to that is to move trackbars to a separate window. For me on OSX the performance increased 4.7 times (from 3 FPS up to 14). I don't know if it works like this always or it's just like that on my computer but I haven't seen such a clue anywhere before so I decided to share.

```
string title = "My window";
int p = 2;

// Create a different window for controls
namedWindow(title + " - controls");
// I show an image once just to resize the window
imshow(title + " - controls", Mat::zeros(1, 500, CV_8UC1));
createTrackbar("Parameter", title + " - controls", &p, 3);

// Create a different window for actual image
namedWindow(title);
while (!done) {
    // Do some calculations
    flip(image, image, p);
    imshow(title, image);
}
```

Comment: additional benefit, that you now can resize it without affecting the trackbar usabilty

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem in OSX-10.9.
And I have resolved the issue in the following ways:

```
port variants opencv
sudo port install opencv +qt4 +tbb +eigen +opencl
```

important option is "+qt4" only, the other options are extra.

OpenCV support Qt for GUI backend. And I suspect the cause of the problem is in the implementation of the default GUI backend.

I was able to virtually eliminates the problem by re-build OpenCV library with Qt support and re-install(update).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this seemed to be an issue with the Anaconda distribution of OpenCV.

Installing OpenCV with pip fixed my performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tune

```
cv2.waitKey(value)
```

I used cv2.waitKey(100) and works smoothly