# What is wrong with my trackbar?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have built a successful edge detection program using `OpenCV` which uses my Macbook's camera and has options for printing various edges based on different channels in the original image, but when I add a trackbar to allow for changing the tolerance on `Canny`, it is both unresponsive and causes my key presses to slow down.

I suspect I am using this wrong as [a similar error in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913112/speeding-up-opencvs-input-response) caused the same kind of delay, but I'm not sure what is wrong here. Any ideas why my trackbar is not responsive?

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;

int showKind = 0;
int waitCount = 1; // wait for this many milliseconds to check for input

Mat channel(Mat A, int ich); // return the image with only this channel non-zero
Mat BW(Mat A); // return the black and white versin of this image
void myWaitKey();
Mat Blur(Mat A, int kernSize);
Mat Edges(Mat A, double tol1, double tol2);

int tol1 = 25; 
int tol2 = 75; 
int tol2Max = 250;

/// trackbar
void on_trackbar(int, void*) {
    cout << "tol2 = " << tol2 << endl;
}

int main() {
    VideoCapture stream1(0);
    namedWindow("cam", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    if( !stream1.isOpened() ) { 
        cout << "Cannot open camera!" << endl;
    }   

    string trackBarName = "tol2";
    createTrackbar( trackBarName.c_str(), "cam",  &tol2, tol2Max, on_trackbar);

    on_trackbar( tol2, 0); 

    Mat cameraFrame; // showKind = 0
    Mat grey; // showkind = 4
    while( true ) { 
        /// read the cameraFrame
        stream1.read(cameraFrame);

        /// show the cameraFrame
        if( showKind == 0 ) imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
        else if( showKind > 0 && showKind < 4 ) imshow("cam", channel(cameraFrame, showKind));
        else if( showKind == 4 ) imshow("cam", BW(cameraFrame) );
        else if( showKind == 5 ) imshow("cam", Edges(channel(cameraFrame,1), tol1, tol2));
        else if( showKind == 6 ) imshow("cam", Edges(channel(cameraFrame,2), tol1, tol2));
        else if( showKind == 7 ) imshow("cam", Edges(channel(cameraFrame,3), tol1, tol2));
        else if( showKind == 8 ) imshow("cam", Edges(cameraFrame, 25, 75));
        else {
            cout << "ERROR: Unknown showKind = " << showKind << endl;
        }


        myWaitKey();
    }


    return 0;
}

Mat channel(Mat A, int ich) {
    Mat Channel[3];
    Mat B;
    split(A, Channel);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if( ich-1 != i ) Channel[i].setTo(0);
    }
    merge(Channel, 3, B);
    return B;
}
Mat BW(Mat A) {
    Mat B;
    cvtColor( A, B, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    return B;
}

void myWaitKey() {
    int key = waitKey(waitCount);
    if( key == 27 ) {
        cout << "ESC pressed ... exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    // convert showKind
    else if( key == 48 ){ showKind = 0; }
    else if( key == 49 ){ showKind = 1; }
    else if( key == 50 ){ showKind = 2; }
    else if( key == 51 ){ showKind = 3; }
    else if( key == 52 ){ showKind = 4; }
    else if( key == 53 ){ showKind = 5; }
    else if( key == 54 ){ showKind = 6; }
    else if( key == 55 ){ showKind = 7; }
    else if( key == 56 ){ showKind = 8; }
}

Mat Blur(Mat A, int kernSize) {
    //Mat G = BW(A);
    Mat C;
    // C is now black and white
    blur(A, C, Size(kernSize,kernSize));

    return C;
}

Mat Edges(Mat A, double tol1, double tol2) {
    Mat G = BW(Blur(A,4));
    Mat E;
    Canny(G, E, tol1, tol2);
    A.copyTo(G, E);
    return G;
}
```

Comment: Instead of many cases of `else if` in `myWaitKey` function you can write `else if (key >= 48 && key <= 56) { showKind = key - 48; } else {//error}`

Comment: Is it better when you increase the waitKey timeout? The doc says it is the time the image is shown, therefore you show the image for one ms and then wait for the next frame?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the trouble in trackbar implementation on Mac OS X.

Maybe this answer can help:
[OpenCV trackbar performance in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349535/opencv-trackbar-performance-in-osx)

Answer (score 0):

- Refer below sample code.I have write this demo code.Hope this will help you.

  ```
  #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  using namespace cv;

  /// Global variables

  Mat src, src_gray;
  Mat dst, detected_edges;

  int edgeThresh = 1;
  int lowThreshold;
  int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
  int ratio = 3;
  int kernel_size = 3;
  char* window_name = "Edge Map";

  void CannyThreshold(int, void*)
  {
     /// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
     blur( src_gray, detected_edges, Size(3,3) );

     /// Canny detector
     Canny( detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );

     /// Using Canny's output as a mask, we display our result
     dst = Scalar::all(0);

     src.copyTo( dst, detected_edges);
     imshow( window_name, dst );
  }
  int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
     /// Load an image
     src = imread( argv[1] );

     if( !src.data )
     { return -1; }

     dst.create( src.size(), src.type() );

    cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    createTrackbar( "Min Threshold:", window_name, &lowThreshold, max_lowThreshold, CannyThreshold );

    CannyThreshold(0, 0);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
  }
  ```